# How to check for numpy.float64(0)?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to filter all values with 0. The data type is `numpy.float64`.
I have tried `numpy.float64(0.0001)`, but is there any way that below code gives me a `True`?

`numpy.float64(0) == 0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float values may not equate correctly due to rounding errors. There is a function `numpy.isclose` which can be used to check for equivalence within a certain tolerance.

```
import numpy as np

np.float64(0) == 0 # for me
>>> True

# however a small, almost zero, number gives False
np.float64(1e-19) == 0
>>> False

np.isclose(np.float64(0), 0)
>>> True

np.isclose(np.float64(1e-19), 0)
>>> True
```